# Why moving template method with rvalue reference parameter gives unresolved external symbol error?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a simple class to illustrate the problem:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void Method1(T&& a) {};
};
```

Then in my main:

```
    double a = 0;

    ClassA classA;
    classA.Method1(a);
```

This compiles fine. But when I move the `Method1` implementation to a cpp file, like so...

Header:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void Method1(T&& a);
};
```

Implementation:

```
template<typename T>
void ClassA::Method1(T&& a) {}

template void ClassA::Method1<double>(double&&);
```

I receive the error message in Visual Studio 2013

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ClassA::Method1(double &)" (??$Method1@AAN@ClassA@@QAEXAAN@Z) referenced in function _wmain

Now if in the main I replace the call to `Method1` to 
`classA.Method1(std::move(a))`

it compiles fine. Why does the header only version compiles fine without the `std::move` whereas the version with the implementation requires a `std::move` to compile?

Comment: The template gets instantiated as a member function accepting an lvalue reference, because this is what you pass. See Meyers' lecture [https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers ] on the subject.

Comment: How come this question was closed twice as a duplicate of *"templates must be in a header"*, when OP's problem concerns explicit instantiation wrt. forwarding-references? I haven't seen a similar question on SO. I can't reopen it for the second time myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
template <typename T>
void Method1(T&& a);
```

`T&&` is a *forwarding-reference*, rather than an *rvalue reference*.

Now, the call:

```
classA.Method1(a);
```

deduces `T` to be `double&`. The explicit instantiation you provide:

```
template void ClassA::Method1<double>(double&&);
```

is only for *rvalue* expressions. This is why it compiles and links when you turn `a` into an *xvalue* (a kind of an rvalue) with `std::move`.

Try the following explicit instantiation:

```
template void ClassA::Method1<double&>(double&);
```

Still, you don't cover all possibilities a forwarding reference can take, so better move the implementation of `Method1` to a header file with the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you've given to the explicit instantiation are incorrect. The lvalue instantiation would be `Method1<double&>(double&);`.